# How to show GridView in tooptip in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, tooltip

Normally what happens, a single or more lines are shown as a tooltip. What I need is to show a gridview as a tooltip. Actually in my project i need to show all the notes associated with a stock in a gridview.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView in a tooltip?  *gringe*

Why don't you use a Sql Data Reader to fetch the data, then set the server control's tool tip text to that?

Comment: Thanks Cen, Actually each stock# contains 'N' number of notes associated with it. The notes are stored in a seperate table.

Comment: I understand that.  However, that fact doesn't mean you need to use a GridView to display it.

Answer (score 2):

As you are working on the web; why not use a dynamic DIV or the equivalent and have a JS function that loads it with the relevant content and moves it to where you want it upon the mouseover event of the control you want to display the tooltip for?

Comment: use jquery tooltips, they are easy to use and look nice.

Comment: @Daniel Elliott Can you provide any link which explains an example of what you have mentioned above...?